# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW'

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

Say something!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br/>
  File "speechrecognition.py", line 17, in <module><br/>
    print("You said: " + r.recognize_google(audio))<br/>
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 828, in recognize_google<br/>
    convert_width=2  # audio samples must be 16-bit<br/>
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 448, in get_flac_data<br/>
    startup_info.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW  # specify that the wShowWindow field of `startup_info` contains a value<br/>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW'<br/>
```

Comment: have you imported the `subprocess` module?

Comment: yes i have imported subprocess

Comment: this is my program                                                                              
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)
try:
    print("You said: " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

Comment: I'm sorry but your code is not readable, please format it accordingly. However from what I can see you have not imported the subprocess module, just the speech_recognition.

Comment: i have imported still i have error

Comment: You have imported speech_recognition. I'm talking about the subprocess module.

Comment: after import subprocess  there is same error. what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of [research](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35896762#c2) it seems that in Python 2.7 version (the one you are using) you have to [use](https://bugs.python.org/issue9861) `subprocess._subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` instead of `subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW`. The latter was added after the 2.7 version.

Comment: problem solved by using bing api r.recognize_bing(audio, key=BING_KEY) it is better then google api and it works good in windows without any error